# VS Code install C# extension with local OmniSharp

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Due to limitations with my current work setup, I'm trying to do a local installation of the VS Code C# extension. I can install it fine using the marketplace or a `.vsix`, but run into issues where it tries to install the required OmniSharp toolset.

As a result of this I have installed a local version of OmniSharp and have set the `omnisharp.path` setting in VS Code to point at this local installation. My issue is that instead of using this, the extension will still try and download a version of OmniSharp.

Is there a way of working around this, without having to set up VS Code to work nicely with our network (probably proxy issues)?

---

*Extension manager output for reference:*

```
Updating C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'    Retrying from 'https://omnisharpdownload.blob.core.windows.net/ext/omnisharp-win-x64-1.23.2.zip' Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)'   Retrying from 'https://vsdebugger.blob.core.windows.net/coreclr-debug-1-12-5/coreclr-debug-win7-x64.zip' 
Installing package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'
Failed at stage: installPackages
Error: end of central directory record signature not found

Finished
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is due to restriction from corporate proxy setup. You can follow the workaround from here --> https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1209935/VS-Code-NET-Core-Offline-installation-of-extension

It is working for me. But I have changed the path to `%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.14.0\.omnisharp` to make it work.