# How to make VS Code have some extensions installed by default in remote containers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-devcontainer

I know that I can use the `extensions` property of the `devcontainers.json` file to tell VS Code about the extensions I want to be there when I start my remote container session.
I also develop .NET and I know that these components are needed:

Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: Linux, x86_64, name=ubuntu, version=18.04

```
Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)' (36011 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)'

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (Linux / x64)' (3411 KB).................... Done!
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)'

Downloading package 'Razor Language Server (Linux / x64)' (61682 KB).................... Done!
Installing package 'Razor Language Server (Linux / x64)'

Finished
```

So as you can see, each time I start the container the list of extensions have to be installed and these dependencies should also be installed.

Is there a way that I embed these dependencies and extensions once inside my docker image, so that they are there always?

Because we have an infrastructure that deletes containers randomly (chaos engineering), the current behavior is extremely inefficient. Each time a container comes up we have to wait a lot to see these being installed.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible (at least not right now). Those dependencies are defined and acquired by individual extensions (you pasted what the C# extension generated), so they won't be covered anywhere else.

While you might find it inefficient, the extension authors (including me) find it friendly, as

- It allows latest dependencies to acquire easily.
- It allows platform specific dependencies to be downloaded on demand.
- It also keeps extensions themselves small.

> [VSCode Marketplace is introducing some new feature](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3431) that might ultimately solve this, so you might keep an eye on that. But even if Marketplace is ready, you need individual extensions to adapt to those changes.

Comment: Not true, you can use a custom Dockerfile and make sure your deps are already there.

Comment: @TheFool then you'd better give your own answer to prove the feasibility.

Comment: Why would I, if microsoft has a full repo of those ? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers

Comment: @TheFool none of those container definitions by Microsoft embeds any of inner dependencies (such as "OmniSharp for Linux (x64)" mentioned in the question), so I wonder how you drew a conclusion that quickly.

Comment: Omnisharp is a regular package. What stops  you to install it upfront in the same fashion as the other stuff? Look how many apt packages and stuff they install in [this script](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/blob/main/containers/dotnet/.devcontainer/library-scripts/common-debian.sh). Why can't you just put [this stuff](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs/blob/master/doc/server-installation.md) along there ?

Comment: @TheFool Visual Studio Code extensions do not follow "the same fashion as other stuff" unfornately. Those dependencies are acquired on the fly and put into the extension content folder (not globally) for various reasons (so you cannot expect apt or other channel to provide you the installer in advance).

Comment: Some people say you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554000/vs-code-install-c-sharp-extension-with-local-omnisharp.

Comment: The go extension is also just using the go tools from your gobin. It's searching for those in the system and if not present, it offers you to install them into gobin. Afterwards, you can use them even outside vscode. So what you refer to may be applicable for some packages, but definitely not for all. See https://github.com/golang/vscode-go#tools

Comment: @LexLi, as I see it in the OP's question, each time a container is loaded for debugging it downloads 100MB of stuff. Are you saying it's impossible to be prevented? Because as a .NET Developer I've always seen that Microsoft solutions include ways to cache stuff. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I wrote VSCode extensions, so I am quite certain at least for now nothing better can be done here. Hope seems to be coming if you check out GitHub issues like [this](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3431#issuecomment-559253761), but won't come easily as you need each of the extensions to adapt to those changes.